# Add listener OnReady to extjs ComboBox

Tags: javascript, ajax, combobox, extjs4.1, onready

Is there anyway to execute a function just when a combobox is ready?

I'm having troubles with this because at the end of the Ext.OnReady it seems like sometimes the combo is not ready and calling a function to fill it's value with an ajax call it causes a lot of troubles.

I'm looking for a proper way for doing this instead of

```
setTimeout(function(){myDataFiller();},300);
```

Comment: Try with afterRender() listener for combo

Comment: Tried with:
<pre>listeners: {afterrender: function(t,o){ getInfoProduct();}},</pre>
But it has the same behaviour. :S

Comment: can you post your code snippet of combo?

Comment: It sounds more like you have some timing problem with the ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a rendering problem based on cpu.

I made some test on Intel Core 2 Duo and I could reproduce the error. After that I tried on i7 cpu and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var combo = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
    /* config settings, blah blah blah */
    listeners: {
        afterrender: {
            single: true,
            fn: function(combobox){
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    /* request settings */
                    success: function(data){
                        var value;
                        /* process your data response */
                        combobox.setValue(value);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Or if you already have the value from your Ajax request, you can just set the value directly in the `afterrender` function. Note the use of `single: true` above. This means the function will only execute once, so that you won't end up resetting the value by mistake if something causes your combobox to re-render.

Comment: The first way you propose was what I did after Jai comment, and didn't workout.